# max row=16,777,216 , Can't find the max columns in Datatable

Tags: c#, .net

The maximum number of rows that a `DataTable` can store is `16,777,216`

**Datatable** max rows - **16,777,216**,

**Datatable** max columns - **????**

Can't seem to find the max columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe its limited by memory(RAM).

You can try a small program

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
{
    for(int i = 0;i<1000000000000;i++)
        dt.Columns.Add(i.ToString)
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Some limit exception!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just over 1,000 though if you are seriously asking this question then maybe you need to look at your data structure rather than datatable limitations.

It might help to explain why you need so many columns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but in my learning i think it should be same but i don't know exactly and this question was just to grow theoretical knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

int.MaxValue but you are likely to get an OutOfMemoryException first, depending on what the actual data.