# Columns limitations on DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net

I'm trying to load a big csv file into a `DataTable`. The file contains about 2200 columns and 13K rows.

I've create the `Datatable` but when I'm trying to add a row to that table nothing happens (neither exceptions nor errors, but the row doesn't appear in the `DataTable`).

I've checked in debug that the row really had all the data and wasn't empty and saw the `DataTable` also had all the columns in it - seems that the `DataTable` add function doesn't work. I tried deleting columns from the csv file and found out that it all worked well when there were about 800 columns.

According to the MSDN documentation there is a row limitation of 16,777,216 - I wasn't even closed to that, but I haven't seen any columns limitations.

Anyone has seen this problem before? Why the add function doesn't work when there are more than 2k columns? Is it really a columns limitation for `DataTable` or there's something I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
StreamReader reader= new StreamReader(filePath); 

// first line contains the names of the columns                       
string strFirstLine = reader.ReadLine();
string strRow;
string[] strColms = strFirstLine.Split(',');                

foreach (string s in strColms)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(s);
}

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{                                                
    strRow = reader.ReadLine();
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();                                                
    row.ItemArray = strRow.Split(',');                        
    dt.Rows.Add(row); 
}
```

p.s. tried using the `AcceptChanges` functions but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656100/max-row-16-777-216-cant-find-the-max-columns-in-datatable

Comment: Try adding a couple of checks, like `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strRow))` and `if (1 < row.ItemArray.Length)`, and **else** conditions that display [MessageBox Dialogs](http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show) until you get the code working right.

Comment: Do you need to keep all this data in memory at once? A DataTable is not the most memory efficient structure. If every column had a single char in it, each row would  have 4.25K. That'll eat your memory pretty quickly.
Sorry about not answering the question but maybe this can point you in another direction.

Comment: Do you really need to have all the data in a single table? Normalizing the data into multiple tables might be a good idea. You might want to look into creating a typed DataSet for your data.